# 2D arrays in linear memory

Tags: c, arrays

I'm having trouble creating a 2D array in a struct. Here is my code so far but I'm sure it's wrong The array is stored in the char pointer in the struct but the array must be for floats so that has me confused as well:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX_ROWS 5000
#define MAX_COLUMNS 5000

struct array
{
        int rows;
        int columns;
        int order;
        char *base_pointer; /* pointer to array of bytes. In this array, float numbers will be stored (4 bytes each) */
};
 struct array* initialize(int rows, int columns, int order)
 {

  /* Allocate the required memory for the 2D array to store float values (Ex: 1.45) with "rows" and "columns" */
  struct array* array = (struct array*)malloc(rows * columns);
  /* Make sure the size is within 1 to MAX_ROWS and 1 to MAX_COLUMNS specified in main.c. If not return null pointer */
  array->rows = rows;
  array->columns = columns;
  array->order = order;
  /* Initialize the 2D array to the all zeroes (0.0) */
  /* Assign suitable values to all the elements of the structure and return the struct pointer */
  return array;
 }
```

Comment: You need 2 mallocs. One for the struct (3 ints + 1 pointer). And one for the data.

Comment: Any reason it MUST be an array of bytes and not an array of floats? Like float** myArray or float myArray[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLUMNS]? If the answer is no you should do some general readings on how arrays work in C before going any further.

Comment: Yeah it needs to be like this. It's for homework.

Comment: the variable name 'array' is very bad because it is the same as the struct name.  the pointer returned from malloc is allocating rows*columns bytes, but what seems to be wanted is to set the base_pointer with the results of the malloc.  Also, this is returning a pointer to an array that is defined on the stack space of the initialize() function.  That stack space will be corrupted at the next invokation of 'anything' by the calling function.  MUCH better to pass a pointer to an instance of the array struct to the initialization function and simply return an indication of success/failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX_ROWS 5000
#define MAX_COLUMNS 5000

struct array
{
        int rows;
        int columns;
        int order;
        char *base_pointer; /* pointer to array of bytes. In this array, float numbers will be stored (4 bytes each) */
};
struct array* initialize(int rows, int columns, int order)
{
  int i,
      size = columns * rows * sizeof(float);
  /* Allocate the required memory for the 2D array to store float values (Ex: 1.45) with "rows" and "columns" */

  // If you want to allocate both the structure and the internal storage in one malloc:
  /*
  struct array* array = (struct array*) malloc(sizeof(struct array) + size);
  array->base_pointer = &((char*)array)[sizeof(struct array)];
  */

  struct array* array = malloc(sizeof(struct array));
  if(!array) {
    return 0; // error
  }
  array->base_pointer = malloc(size);
  if(!array->base_pointer) {
    return 0; // error
  }

  for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    array->base_pointer[i] = 0;
  }
  /* Make sure the size is within 1 to MAX_ROWS and 1 to MAX_COLUMNS specified in main.c. If not return null pointer */
  array->rows = rows;
  array->columns = columns;
  array->order = order;
  /* Initialize the 2D array to the all zeroes (0.0) */
  /* Assign suitable values to all the elements of the structure and return the struct pointer */
  return array;
 }

 void insert(struct array* arr, int row, int column, float value) {
    float* floatArr = (float*)arr->base_pointer;
    floatArr[(column * arr->rows) + row] = value;
 }

 float retrieve(struct array* arr, int row, int column) {
    float* floatArr = (float*)arr->base_pointer;
    return floatArr[(column * arr->rows) + row];
 }
```

You were allocating the memory required for the internal array and trying to use it for the structure. Instead you need to allocate the memory for the structure then provide it with a pointer to a separate allocation for its internal array `base_pointer`.

Comment: This looks right. Thanks. One more question, how would I try to insert values if I'm given the row index and column index for where I want to insert the value?

Comment: If you want to insert/retrieve at a specific row and column, you will need to offset your index by the row you need to be on then add the column index you need. Here's how I did it (note the insert and retrieve functions): http://ideone.com/6Y6gRs

Comment: The original allocation "pattern" (used in the question) suggested that the OP was looking for a "struct hack"-based solution (and it would be quite appropriate in this case), but this answer performs dual allocation instead of using "struct hack"... I could be wrong about the original intent though.

Comment: this is good, except that the code needs to check after every malloc that the malloc succeeded.  Also, using calloc rather than malloc would pre-set all the bytes to 0x00.  (which is not necessarily float(0) so I would have defined the base_pointer as a pointer to float in the original struct definition and used the for loop to set floats to 0.0.

Comment: @user3629249 I've updated my answer to include checks for failed allocations. I also fixed an issue and included insert and retrieve functions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate some space for the `array` structure first, then you can allocate the memory for your array.

```
struct array {
    /* number of rows isn't necessary, unless you want to do some boundary checking */
    unsigned int columns;
    int order;
    char* data;
};
struct array* array_createf(unsigned int rows, unsigned int columns, int order) {
    /* Allocate the required memory for the 2D array structure */
    struct array * arr = (struct array*)malloc(sizeof(struct array));
    /* Allocate some memory for array´s data */
    arr->data = (char*)malloc(rows*columns*sizeof(float));

    /* store information about the array*/
    arr->rows = rows;
    arr->columns = columns;
    arr->order = order;

    /* return */
    return arr;
}
float array_getf(struct array * arr, unsigned int row, unsigned int column) {
    return array_getfrow(row)[column];
}
void array_setf(struct array * arr, unsigned int row, unsigned int column, float item) {
    array_getfrow(row)[column] = item;
}

float * array_getfrow(struct frray * arr, unsigned int row) {
    return (float*)&arr->data[row*arr->columns*sizeof(float)];
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the data part of the struct needs to be a char*, but it needs to store values of floats.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define MAX_ROWS 5000
#define MAX_COLUMNS 5000

struct array
{
        int rows;
        int columns;
        int order;
        float base_pointer[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLUMNS];
};

 struct array* initialize(int rows, int columns, int order)
 {

  struct array* array = malloc(sizeof(struct array));
  assert(array != NULL);
  array->rows = rows;
  array->columns = columns;
  array->order = order;

  /* Initialize the 2D array to the all zeroes (0.0) */
  memset(array->base_pointer, 0, sizeof(array->base_pointer));
  /* Assign suitable values to all the elements of the structure and return the struct pointer */
  return array;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
struct array* initialize(int rows, int columns, int order)
{
   /* Allocate the required memory for the 2D array */
   struct array* array = malloc(sizeof(struct array));

   /* Make sure the size is within 1 to MAX_ROWS and 1 to MAX_COLUMNS specified in main.c. If not return null pointer */
   array->rows = rows;
   array->columns = columns;
   array->order = order;

   /* Allocate memory for the data of the array and initialize them to all zeroes (0.0) */
   array->base_pointer = calloc(sizeof(float)*rows*columns);

   /* Return the array */
   return array;
}
```